# Is it possible to put translated file to BIM360 Docs?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-bim360

I am trying to translate Revit model to an IFC , and to put it to Bim360 Docs without downloading to computer.

I've tried to create FirstFileVersion from derivativeURN , but i've had an error.

How i can do that?

Comment: The derivative file is stored in your own storage Forge allocates to your account, while the file which is uploaded to BIM 360 is stored in the storage of Autodesk (wip.dm.prod).  I do not see an API that can copy file from one storage to another one. I will double check with engineer team, while you may have to download the derivative firstly, and follow the steps to upload file (also create file item/version) in BIM 360 https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/tutorials/upload-file/

Comment: Our engineer team told me: "unfortunately, there is no api that would copy across buckets. you could directly pipe the GET stream to the PUT stream instead of saving the file, but the bytes would still pass through the user. " . And I think of the sample which transferred file from various storages to Forge bucket, which uses pipe streaming:  https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/bim360appstore-data.management-nodejs-transfer.storage

Comment: Thanks, i'll use Azure storage for that